# READ_TEXT finds the long text only if it's changed

Tags: abap

My program reads a text from the tab "Internal Observations" of transaction code `MM03`, by using `Read_Text` function module.

During the tests I came across with a strange problem. When I run the program only a few texts were showing up. I edited some of those material texts in `MM02` (only with a space or a char, for example `'ABC'` -> `'ABC '`) and they were shown in my program, so I went debugging and saw that the function was working fine for all.

Maybe the problem is almost all of the existing materials were changed in bulk. Have you ever been across this kind of problem?

Here is my program:

```
MOVE: gs_tab_out_f-matnr TO name,
      'IVER'             TO id,
      'MATERIAL'         TO object,
      sy-langu           TO language.

CALL FUNCTION 'READ_TEXT'
  EXPORTING
    id                      = id
    language                = language
    name                    = name
    object                  = object
  TABLES
    lines                   = lines
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS                  = 8.
IF sy-subrc = 0.
  LOOP AT lines INTO line WHERE tdformat EQ '*'.
    WRITE line-tdline TO gs_tab_out_f-descricao.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
```

ENDIF.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Without changing the text in `MM02`, the output is :

```
MATERIAL       TEXT

 1. ASP-AU247
 2. ASP-AU753
 3. ASP-AU842
```

2) Add a trailing space to the text in `MM02` and save it

3) Run the program, the output is:

```
MATERIAL       TEXT

 1. ASP-AU247   *A6 01/09-G/LAMAS
 2. ASP-AU753   *A6 01/09-GREL
 3. ASP-AU842    A6 01/09-FRISO
```

After manually changing the text I can run the transaction and in every single time for those materials the text will be displayed in the right way.

Comment: I don't understand how to reproduce, maybe you execute `READ_TEXT` from a user exit in MM02? Maybe your issue is about how the "[Text Memory](https://help.sap.com/viewer/872c7db8e8ad411c8c3364aceed6e2c1/7.52.5/en-US/4e1649edb8294181e10000000a15822b.html)" works, or maybe the fact that the edited text is saved to the database asynchronously via the [update task](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenupdate_glosry.htm)?

Comment: Thank you very much, I´m going to look for those hints.

Comment: Just to be clear, is that output in `tdline` field of `lines` table that you are seeing through debugger or is that what you are seeing through a program? 
I'm asking because I recall a colleague encountering cases where text was somehow placed with some special symbols which caused it to be displayed incorrectly. By editing through a standard program you would be overwriting "faulty" text.

Comment: This is from the program... My initial thought was that the problem was related with using special characters, but I eddited some of them putting only a symbol like '*' and they were shown.. Throug the debugger  the value from **line-tdline** it´s not being written in **gs_tab_out_f-descricao** for those cases that I never manually edited before

Comment: When you run the program on a text that was not changed, what does READ_TEXT return in LINES? I suspect the action of changing the text changes the TDFORMAT for all lines, which then makes them visible in your program.

Comment: I think that´s really the problem here, never saw that happen, in fact, when the text was never eddited for me before TDFORMAT is coming as '/' instead of '*', i wil test further and if it´s reaaly the problem, I have to do a validation for it... I will let you know if that´s the case.. thank you very much

Comment: The issue '''is probably not related to the code you have posted''', but to the program which "charged the [materials] into the system in bulk", as you say. Can you describe this program? Moreover, was it executed in background or in dialog -I ask in case it's related to the text memory-? (NB: remember that the updates are often done asynchronously, so if you read the texts right after the bulk program, they don't exist yet in database)

Comment: Yep, that is important point, are you reading the standard texts that were changed a moment before or the old ones that were sitting in database for months? Give the program that changes the texts

Comment: Those were the texts that were in database since the first bulk loading into the system. This load was made using a Z program which runs in background. But the program runned months ago... In fact the problem was in **tdformat** which had a different value in those cases, I made a validation for those cases, and it´s now running without problems. But for me it was a new thing, because which makes that value change it´s is loading into the system...